# When trying to use the material theme on Android, my title bar is not using the primary colour

Tags: android, material-design

From my research, it appears that when using the material theme on Android the title bar should take on the primary color but for me, it stays black. I know the theme itself is working as things did change to black when I first applied the `default(dark)` theme. I have this set in the **styles.xml** file:

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The colors referenced from **colors.xml** are working as they show up on the s the de in android studio.

I have tried looking for a way to manually change the title bar but I have only found ways to do it programatically and not through layout files. I have attached a pic of what the title bar currently looks like and what i would like it to look like below:

**Current title bar**

[image: Current title bar]

**What I want it to look like**

[image: What I want it to look like]

Comment: Instead of it try to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` or `Theme.AppCompat.Light.LightActionBar`.

Comment: This still does not use the primary colour for the action bar.

Comment: set the background of toolbar
`android:background="@color/colorPrimary"`

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it in a layout file that doesn't currently have anything to do with a toolbar in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```